# Show hide layout on imageview

Tags: android, android-viewpager

[image]I have a viewpager and i show images in it. It support pinch zoom and double click zoom.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/framelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutViewpager">


    <com.bogdwellers.pinchtozoom.view.ImageViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayoutforbuttons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Save" />



   </RelativeLayout>
// Sudo layout, working as button
  <RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativelayoutforvisibility"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

I want that when user open viewpager, it show full image and if user click on image some button should appear from another(RelativeLayout) layout.
I created an extra layout and set OnClickListener on it.

```
  viewPager = (ImageViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) 
  v.findViewById(R.id.relativelayoutforbuttons);
    relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    RelativeLayout relativelayoutforvisibility =  (RelativeLayout) 
v.findViewById(R.id.relativelayoutforvisibility);
  relativelayoutforvisibility.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(relativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
            {
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            // Show layouts if they're not VISIBLE
            else
            {
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
   myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

    setCurrentItem(selectedPosition);
```

Now my problem is this code work good and show/hide the button containig layout. but it also affect viewpager. I cant swipe left or right and i can't zoom image.
I want whatsapp like full image preview that show forward button when touch.

Comment: Wait, you can't swipe left/right and zoom? You should be at least able to do one thing. Right?

Comment: @Dennis No, i can't do anything. Neither swipe nor zoom.

Comment: Can you post all the code please (what are relativelayoutforvisibility and relativeLayout variables ?) I suppose that you show a layout in front of your ViewPager and this layout take the touch event and don't dispatch it to the ViewPager that is behind the layout.

Comment: Yea, the question is incomplete, hurry up before someone down-votes it

Comment: @Bubu updated the code.

Comment: Upload a picture.

Comment: @Dennis why you need a picture ? before onClick zoom and swipe working. Now i can hide the layout but zoom and swipe not supported. Thres is nothing in picture, only imageview .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Easy Fix :  Set height of your `RelativeLayout` to `wrap_content`

The reason why your touch gestures are not working once you make your `RelativeLayout` visible is because you are using a `FrameLayout` and that "`RelativeLayout`" is now positioned over your `ImageView` this it will `invalidate` the `Touch gestures/events` or in other words, it will "`consume`" that touch gesture and won't allow your `ViewPager` to consume it.

Fix? 
Use [`ConstraintLayout`](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/) and position individual views (which are present inside your `RelativeLayout`) along with your image view.

Here's a random example where you will hide two buttons whenever you'll touch on your `ImageView`. I will not post the java code showing `onClickListeners`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/shareButton"
      android:text="Share Button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
      tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/sendButton"
      android:text="Send Button Button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
      tools:ignore="HardcodedText"/>

  <android.support.constraint.Group
      android:id="@+id/group"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:constraint_referenced_ids="sendButton,shareButton"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then inside your onClickListener

`yourGroup.setVisiblility(View.GONE);` and so on..

**UPDATE (Required by the user)**

`Groups` are a part of `ConstraintLayout`

```
 <android.support.constraint.Group
              android:id="@+id/group"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:visibility="visible"
              app:constraint_referenced_ids="button4,button9" />
```

Inside your java code

```
import android.support.constraint.Group;
```

then in order to initialize them

```
Group group = findViewById(R.id.yourGroupId);
```

and then set the visibility

```
group.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Wait what? Can you post the image?

Comment: Same problem after using ConstrantLayout. I just only changed framelayout with ConstriantL,  and nothing.

Comment: Read the answer carefully, I'm asking you to take out the child views from your `RelativeLayout` and position them on the screen along with your `ImageView`

Comment: I don't know how your layout looks like, and i don't even know child views which you want to display over your image view. But I can share my code with you. Wait.

Comment: Do you use Whatsapp ? when we click on image and it show full view. If we click on screen, share and forward button show and hide. Like this

Comment: Ohhhhh, is that so? Should have mentioned that earlier mate. Again, do the same thing. Using `Groups` feature inside your Constraint layout and group all those buttons in that, and toggle the visibility accordingly.

Comment: see the picture from whatsapp, that's i want.

Comment: on what i should set onClickListener ?

Comment: on your `ImageView`

Comment: sorry to bother you, but how i define group in java. There's no proper documentation.

Comment: now problem is i have viewpager and onClick method is not working.

Comment: try setting `onClickListener` on your `ViewPager`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173751/discussion-between-dennis-and-mukeshsoni).

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `relativelayoutforvisibility` take all the place (width and height = match_parent) and it is in front of your ViewPager, so this layout take all touches event and don't dispatch them to your ViewPager (that is behind the layout).
You can add `android:clickable="false"` and `android:focusable="false"` to your `relativelayoutforvisibility`

Comment: The correct solution would be to re-create your UI and not add additional layout. (it will make it easy for the phone to render it as well)  
@Babu check my answer and let me know your thoughts over it.

Comment: @Dennis then on whick layout should i set OnClickListener ?

Comment: Kindly read my answer. What he should do is take out all the views from his `RelativeLayout` and position them along with his `ImageView`. This is a good practice. "One should not add unnecessary layer of parent views in their layout file`

Comment: @Bubu see the picture from whatsapp. tha's i want.